Trying to register default QuartzSchedulerMBean in Spring
This is a follow up of Trying to register default QuartzSchedulerMBean where it is mentioned to set the JMX property in quartz properties. But I am trying to set it in the Java bean. My config mentioned below.
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(Map<String, JobDetail> jobMap,
        Map<String, Trigger> triggers) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());

    JobDetail[] jobs = jobMap.values().toArray(new JobDetail[0]);
    Trigger[] tr = triggers.values().toArray(new Trigger[0]);

    schedulerFactory.setJobDetails(jobs);
    schedulerFactory.setTriggers(tr);
    
    return schedulerFactory;
}

How to set "org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true" in Java?

Are you using Spring Boot? If so, I believe setting spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export = true in application.properties should do the trick if you're using spring-boot-starter-quartz.
